# Firebase Auth, crashing on verify phone auth, android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app is crashing while verify phone auth, the SMS is received successfully but is crashing when clicking the verify button, not all devices, 20% of devices from play store are crashing. This is the log from Play Console.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkArgument (Preconditions.java:9)
  at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential.<init> (PhoneAuthCredential.java:60)
  at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential.zza (PhoneAuthCredential.java:10)
  at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential (PhoneAuthProvider.java:2)
  at com.udaan.recstudentportalV2.VerifyMobile.matchOtp (VerifyMobile.java:2)
  at com.udaan.recstudentportalV2.VerifyMobile.access$200 (VerifyMobile.java:2)
  at com.udaan.recstudentportalV2.VerifyMobile$3.onClick (VerifyMobile.java:2)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:7862)
  at android.widget.TextView.performClick (TextView.java:15004)
  at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick (MaterialButton.java:3)
  at android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:7831)
  at android.view.View.access$3600 (View.java:879)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:29359)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8167)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:496)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by recreating it. This situation occurs when user clicks verify button before sending OTP. An initial check if OTP is sent or not before calling the getCredential() method will help to rectify this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following way i used send otp with firebase its working perfectly

```
 private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        verificationCallbacks;

 //On Create
 Send_Number_tofirebase(phoneNumber);

     public void Send_Number_tofirebase(String phoneNumber){
    setUpVerificatonCallbacks();
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            this,
            verificationCallbacks);
}


    private void setUpVerificatonCallbacks() {
   Functions.Show_loader(this,false,true);
    verificationCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {

                       Functions.cancel_loader();
                        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);

                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                    Functions.cancel_loader();

                    Log.d("response",e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(Login_Phone_A.this, "Enter Correct Number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        // Invalid request
                    } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                        // SMS quota exceeded
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(String verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {

                    Functions.cancel_loader();

                    phoneVerificationId = verificationId;
                    resendToken = token;
                    sendtotxt.setText("Send to ( "+phoneNumber+" )");
                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(Login_Phone_A.this, R.anim.in_from_right);
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(Login_Phone_A.this, R.anim.out_to_left);
                    viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);

                }
            };
}
```

Hear on Verify Button Press

```
 public void verifyCode(View view) {
String code=""+digit1.getText().toString()+digit2.getText().toString()+digit3.getText().toString()+digit4.getText().toString()+digit5.getText().toString()+digit6.getText().toString();
if(!code.equals("")){
   Functions.Show_loader(this,false,true);
   PhoneAuthCredential credential =
           PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(phoneVerificationId, code);
   signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
}else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enter the Correct varification Code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```